# Prove that $|x'| + |x| + 1 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, absolute-value, stability-in-odes

Studying a field of analysis of differential equations within Dynamical Systems, I came upon the following problem which I do not know how to proceed :

> *Prove that the differential equation :*
>   $$|x'| + |x| + 1 = 0$$
>   *has no solutions.*

I have handled some problems like : *prove that the solutions of $x'' + x + x^3 =0$* have solutions that are set over $\mathbb R$, which are handled by multiplying and integrating or by handling them as *duffing equations*, but I cannot seem how to proceed in this one. Any thorough help will be appreciated !

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the LHS always at least $1$?

Comment: @quasi What do you mean by saying that the left hand side is always at least 1 ? I can't understand what you're pointing at, just asking.

Comment: Is $x$ a function of (say) $y$ and $x' = \frac{d x}{d y}$ ?

Comment: The left-hand-side (LHS) of your differential equation can't assume values less than $1$.

Comment: @quasi Yes, I understood this and it's obvious. But what does that say ?

Comment: It says that there's no such function $x(t)$. It's a differential equation which self-evidently has no solution.

Comment: Yep, understood now. It was obvious from the beginning anyway, but I wasn't sure it would be a viable answer (felt too simple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *any* differentiable function $x$, $|x'|+|x|+1\geqslant1>0$.

Comment: So that means it cannot be a differential equation ? To say the truth, sorry if it sounds weird but I never heard of that rule.

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos It is a differential equation, but it has no solutions. Which rule are you talking about?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos It means there cannot be a function $x$ such that the left side is equal to the right side. The left side is a function of $t$ that never goes below $1$. The right hand side is the constant function $0$. They can never be the same function, so the equation can never be satisfied.

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Yes, that's right. I've edited your question in order to highlight its most important part. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: It's no problem. I just wasn't sure whether a bold claim could be made about it being an impossible equation, that was all. It was obvious to me too that the equation would be impossible, but it's an exercise in a paragraph with a ton of difficult and huge exercises, so it felt weird to be an one-line solution.

Answer (score 2):

This equation doesn't need to be "differential" to be impossible. No non-negative quantity added to $1$ can yield $0$.

Comment: This is in fact so obvious that it is dubious whether you reproduced the question faithfully.